# What is the difference between a primitive class and primitive data type?

Tags: java, class, primitive-types

I am reading a book on Java, and they seem to use the two terms "primitive class" and "primitive data type" interchangeably.

What's the difference between the two? I understand that Integer is a wrapper class, and people reference int as a primitive data type. So is it also a primitive class?

Comment: a `primitive class` is a `wrapper class` for a `primitive type`. So for `int` you have `Integer`, for `double` you have `Double` and so on

Comment: Sounds a bit oxymoronic to me...

Comment: I don't think I've heard "primitive class" before, and if I did, my first thought would be "huh?" To my knowledge, the JLS and official Java tutorials don't call anything a primitive class. As @Lino wrote, your book _probably_ means what most people (and the JLS) refer to as a wrapper class.

Comment: out of curiosity, what book is that?

Comment: It's a study guide resource my school provided to study for an intro to Computer Science exam, don't know why I said it was a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're confusing their vernacular here.

A primitive is a data type which is *not* an object.  `int`, `float`, `double`, `long`, `short`, `boolean` and `char` are examples of primitive data types.  You can't invoke methods on these data types and they don't have a high memory footprint, which is their striking difference from classes.

**Everything else** is a class (or class-like in the case of interfaces and enums).  Pretty much everything that begins with an upper-case letter, like `String`, `Integer` are classes.  Arrays also classify as not-primitives, even though they may hold them.  `int[]` isn't a primitive type but it holds primitives.

The only thing that could realistically come *close* would be the wrapper classes, [as explained by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html), but even then, they're *still* classes, and not primitives.

Comment: I think it would be more correct to say everything else is a "Type" (which includes classes, array types, data types, etc.)

Comment: @Kapep:  If I recall correctly, you can access primitives reflectively through a `Type` or `Type`-like class, so I'd hesitate overloading that terminology.  It's easier to think of these as classes to not confuse one in the future.

Comment: I have to correct myself, the JLS says there are two basic kinds of Types: PrimitiveType and ReferenceType. So that would make everything else is ReferenceType. But anyway I agree with you that it's probably more helpful and less confusing to just call it class or class-like here.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger:  It's still returns a class, though.  dasblinkenlight reminded me of what the name(s) were, but I still firmly hold that those are classes and not primitive classes.

Comment: Right.  I'm not interested in debating this much further @CarlosHeuberger, but there are key differences between primitives and classes, and that should be maintained.  The method, from my understanding, is unfortunately named, and would confuse people into thinking that they have a primitive class of some concoction instead of...a *class*.

Answer (score 5):

Primitive class has a special meaning in the context of reflection APIs: when you need to retrieve a method that takes a parameter of primitive type, you need a primitive class object that corresponds to that primitive type.

This is important if you must distinguish between overloads that take primitives and overloads that take wrappers:

```
void someMethod(int n);
void someMethod(Integer n);
```

There are two ways to obtain this class object:

- Using class literal, e.g. `int.class`, or
- Using `TYPE` member of the corresponding *wrapper* class, e.g. `Integer.TYPE`.

This is not the same class as the class representing the primitive wrapper. In other words,

```
int.class != Integer.class
```

Comment: That's what I was on about.  I knew that one could use `int.class` or any equivalent primitive class declaration to get at it in reflection.